# How to map nested object into an existing nested object?

Tags: c#, automapper

I have the following classes.

```
public class Person {
  public string Name { get; set; }
  public Address Address { get; set; }
}

public class PersonDTO {
  public string Name { get; set; }
  public Address Address { get; set; }
}
```

I create a standard mapping using

```
Mapper.CreateMap<Person, PersonDTO>();
```

Then I'd like to map a `Person` into an existing `PersonDTO` hierarchy in that way that the existing `Address` will be updated instead of reference copied if you know what I mean.

```
var person = new Person() {
  Name = "Test",
  Address = new Address() {
    Country = "USA",
    City = "New York"
  }
};
var personDTO = new PersonDTO() {
  Name = "Test2",
  Address = new Address() {
    Country = "Canada",
    City = "Ottawa"
  }
};

Mapper.Map(person, personDTO);
```

I'd like to fulfill the following tests.

```
Assert.AreNotEqual(person.Address, personDTO.Address);
Assert.AreEqual(person.Address.Country, personDTO.Address.Country);
Assert.AreEqual(person.Address.City, personDTO.Address.City);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just create a map between `Address` and itself like this:

```
Mapper.CreateMap<Address, Address>();
```

Please note that the following test:

```
Assert.AreNotEqual(person.Address, personDTO.Address);
```

Might not give you want you want if `Address` defines an `Equals` method. From what I understand from the question, you want to check for reference equality.

If you are using NUnit, you should use `Assert.AreNotSame`.

In general you can use `object.ReferenceEquals` to check for reference equality like this:

```
bool same_object = object.ReferenceEquals(person.Address, personDTO.Address);
```

Comment: Thank you, I'm gonna try this. The assertion was just kind of a pseude-codish indication, thanks for the hints though.

Comment: Yes this works nicely, thank you. However in the real world I'm using `DynamicMap` for simplicity and it would be a lot of boilerplate code to define all these self-mappings explicitly. Isn't there any kind of implicit way to make this behavior the default? Or could I create my own method which would try to use `CreateMissingTypeMaps` for nested mappings too?

Comment: There is not a way that I know of. But maybe there is one. Consider posting a question about this.